# Hosting single page Angular app on Heroku using Express

Tags: angularjs, express, heroku

I'm new to Angular and am trying to host a little app I built on Heroku, and I'm understanding I'd need a webserver. I've heard of Express, but never used it before. If someone would point out what I need to add to my `server.js` file in order for me to be able to host it on Heroku; that'd be much appreciated! Also, if there are better, easier solutions out there that would allow my app to be hosted on Heroku, please let me know.

My file structure is as follows:

```
Project/

|-- components
    |-- project.controller.js
    |-- project.factory.js
|-- css
|   |-- style.css
|   |
|-- node_modules   
|
|-- scripts
|   |-- app.js
|
|
|-- index.html
|-- server.js
|-- package.json
|-- README
```

The very simple code from my app.js file in `/scripts`) is:

```
(function() {



"use strict";

  angular
    .module('project', ['ngMaterial', 'firebase'])
    .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
      $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('teal')
        .warnPalette('deep-orange')
        .accentPalette('indigo');
    });

})();
```

And the code that I've got so far from my `server.js` file is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/index.html');
});

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT);
```

I'm understanding things are missing. I'd greatly appreciate some help in figuring this out. Thanks in advance! I'll gladly share more code if that could help.

Comment: to get help better for you to provide your package.json for us. In that case we would see what you use at `npm start ` command (default server start command for heroku nodejs hosting)

Comment: If you don't have any idea what is it, i suggest you to read article on heroku site. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs.

Comment: @VladDekhanov here is the `package.json` file:

`{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "userName",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.1",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-aria": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-material": "^0.11.4",
    "mdi": "^1.7.22",
    "express": "^4.15.0"
  }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You should add `start` in the `scripts` section from `package.json` where you gonna start your server. If you don't use any task runner such as `grunt` or `gulp` you would use `node` command to start your server. For your `package.json` check example below.

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "Project",
    "main": "index.js",
    "author": "userName",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./server.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
         "angular": "^1.6.1",
         "angular-animate": "^1.5.8",
         "angular-aria": "^1.5.8",
         "angular-material": "^0.11.4",
         "mdi": "^1.7.22",
         "express": "^4.15.0"
    }
}
```

Now you would test this though command prompt with command `npm start` in the context of the project. If server get starting then you would try to deploy your app to heroku.